# REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS is throwing invalid references in sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Consider a view `branch_cust` defined as follows:

```
Create view branch_cust as                      
select 
   branch_name, 
   customer_name 
from depositor, account  
where depositor.account_number = account.account_number
```

suppose that a view is materialized; that is the view is computed and stored. Write a trigger to maintain the view, that is, to keep it up-to-date on insertions to and deletions from depositor or account. Do not bother about updates.

I tried doing an insert trigger on depositor using referencing new table as 
But it is throwing errors.
This is the code.

```
create or replace trigger insert_dep 
after insert on depositor REFERENCING NEW TABLE as inserted  
FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN 
insert into branch_cust select branchname, cusname 
from inserted, account 
where inserted.account = account.acc; end;
```

Comment: Please list the errors you are getting. That will allow the SO community members to understand the problem easily and help you.

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html) did you find the syntax `referencing new table as`? Triggers on views also must be defined as `instead of` triggers

Comment: Error report -
ORA-04074: invalid REFERENCING name
04074. 00000 -  "invalid REFERENCING name"
*Cause:    An invalid name was given in the referencing clause.
*Action:   Verify the referencing name is not a reserved word. This was the error i got while compiling the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear, is branch_cust a table or view or materialized view ??
I will try to answer for all 3 cases :

1. branch_cust is view : and looking at the given DDL by you its a complex view, which means DMLs on it will fail. Also, since you are inserting into branch_cust(which is formed from table depositor) using a trigger which is also upon depositor you will get mutating error even if you make the view Simple.
   so, this scenario will never work out.
2. branch_cust is materialized view : you cannot perform insert into a materialized view. so, trigger will fail
3. branch_cust is table : this can be achieved if you want to keep a separate copy of depositor data joined by account. but i suggest not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> suppose that a view is materialized

Then it makes no sense in *inserting into* it, as those changes would be lost anyway at the first refresh.

Therefore, as it seems that you wanted to refresh it as soon as changes are made in its source table, set it to **refresh on commit**. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create materialized view mv_emp
  2    refresh complete
  3    on commit
  4  as
  5  select deptno, sum(sal) sumsal
  6  From emp
  7  group by deptno;

Materialized view created.

SQL> select * from mv_emp order by deptno;

    DEPTNO     SUMSAL
---------- ----------
        10      13750
        20      10995
        30       9400

SQL> update emp set sal = sal + 1 where deptno = 10;

3 rows updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from mv_emp order by deptno;

    DEPTNO     SUMSAL
---------- ----------
        10      13753               --> new value for DEPTNO = 10
        20      10995
        30       9400

SQL>
```